# PowerShell 2.0 Run one SQL File (having multi SP and Functions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, deployment, powershell-2.0

I have a `.sql` file which has multiple stored procedures and functions script in it.

I don't want to use `Invoke` commands because my server doesn't support them.

Currently I am using below code which works fine if my `.sql` file has only one stored procedure or function.

```html
$scriptDetail = Get-Content $sqlScriptLocation | Out-String 
$scriptDetail = $scriptDetail -creplace 'GO',''
$scriptDetail = $scriptDetail -replace 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON',''
$scriptDetail = $scriptDetail -replace 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON',''
$ConnectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$cred;Database=$database;” 
$sqlCon = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $ConnectionString
$sqlCon.Open()
$sqlCmd = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlCon
$sqlCmd.CommandText = $scriptDetail
$sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
$sqlCon.Close()
```

I am replacing `GO` and other two commands in above code because they casused errors like

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'GO'
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@variableName"

Comment: $sqlScriptLocation = "C:\All_Restore_PROCEDUREFunctiond.sql"

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with solution after Some digging, read the complete file and put it in an array and then run the ForEach loop, it will get each line in ForEach loop put a condition if its not equal to "GO" add it into another array else array(in which you are adding each line) execute it
Code is below

```html
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=" + $YourServerName + ";Database="  + $YourDatabaseName + ";User ID= "  + $YourUserName + ";Password="  + $YourDbPassword + ";" 


$DirectoryPath = "C:\FolderName"
$Dep_SqlFiles = get-childitem -Recurse   $DirectoryPath -Include "*.sql"

$Dep_Info_DataEntry = @(Get-Content $Dep_SqlFiles.FullName) #Get all info of each file and put it in array



foreach($SQLString in  $Dep_Info_DataEntry)
{
   if($SQLString -ne "go") 
      { 
      #Preparation of SQL packet 
      $SQLToDeploy += $SQLString + "`n" 
      }
  Else
      {
        try{
      $SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLToDeploy, $SQLConnection) 
 $SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
#use this if you want to log the output
#$SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar() | Out-File YourLogFile  -Append 

        }
        Catch
        {

        }
    
$SQLToDeploy = ""
      }

}
```